# How to render # Symbol from Razor, MVC

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am trying to display the # symbol from a razor file but I get it rendered as the letter N.

I have tried with:

```
&num ,
&#x23 ,
@Html.Raw("#"), 
<text>#</text> and so on.
```

but it always turns into the letter N. Any suggestion?

Code Example using tag suggested: It is just html markup within a .cshtml file, I have got the same rendered result for all browsers.

```
 <section>                                       

  .....
  <p>...and Microsoft SQL Server using C <text>#</text> and.</p>
  ..........

</section>
```

[image: Html rendered image]

Comment: Can you add the code which you have tried? It becomes easy to get the context.

Comment: Have you tried in different browsers ? What does the resulting HTML source code render the `#` as ? And have you tried with `&num;` (note the semicolon)

Comment: I have edited my question to show more details. I still do not find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you for example use the font [Rationale](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Rationale) from Google Fonts (I think it looks close to your font), the `#` is this symbol:

[image]

You could simply use another font for the part where you want to display C#:

```
<span style="font-family:'Arial'";>C#</span>
```

Comment: It is totally right. Thanks for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
<text>#</text>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately I got the same result,

Comment: Thanks @AmirhosseinYari, but it does not work for me, could it be a kind of configuration from my web application? I have edited my question to show more details

Answer (score 1):

1. There should be a semicolon at the end of the HTML entity `&num;`.
2. Make sure you don't you use a fancy font which does not support such a trivial
   character.

Comment: Thanks @Anton. you are right. My "fancy" font does not support it. I would not like to change the font of the whole page, do you know a technique to  deal with it without to change the font of the entire page?

Comment: @D.B yep, but I see Claudio P was faster :)

Answer (score 0):

try this ;-)

```
@Html.Raw("&#35;")
```